# What to do with teachers who think their subject is "extra special" and gives students too heavy a load?

Tags: teaching

I've had my fair share of teachers who give so much more load than the previous teachers of the same subject. A whole extra project, much more papers, or exercises, etc.

The bigger problem is that there comes a time where in a single semester, several of the teachers think this way, and MOST of them give an extra project/exercise EACH, on top of the current curriculum projects.

This strains the students too much.

How should a student approach these types of situations?

Comment: Easily. Does the required homework, pass the courses with good grades and moves on.

Comment: How do you deal with a boss which asks you to work more than other bosses? What if he gives you a project with a tight deadline?

Comment: @NickS That comparison doesn't work. In a workplace situation, one typically only has one immediate boss. It's up to them to manage the competing demands on their group's time from different customers and different parts of the company.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sadly, this isn't *at all* what it is like in companies. (Almost) nobody is in *one* project only nowadays, and almost nobody has exactly one boss.

Comment: @DavidRicherby your *one* boss is *not* going to be happy when you complain about having *too* many projects. In fact he's not going to be happy to hear anything about any of them at all, besides that they're complete and ready to ship.

Comment: @xLeitix Yet it seems that many job-seekers and employees strongly prefer having one boss to many. That some companies have bloated and inefficient management structures does not mean that well-managed companies don't exist (or should be ignored).

Comment: @djechlin That sounds like more like a caricature of a boss than an actual, effective boss. You'd think a person in charge of a project would want to hear about difficulties encountered by elements of the project, so he can address them, instead of sitting at his table and wondering why it hasn't shipped when he expected it to ship.

Comment: @Superbest nonetheless if the root problem seems to be your difficulty in managing simultaneous projects, either you or his expectations are the problem and I would have to be on the short end of that debate.

Answer (score 11):

This is just what you should be expecting from your postgraduate degree. Each module *is* special. It should push you further than any undergraduate module would.

You are also now assumed to be a grown-up, and to learn how to manage your own workload, and to balance competing demands on your time and energy. Part of what a Masters or Doctorate course does, is to teach you research skills, and project management. These are (at least, in the courses I've been involved with), an important part of the process.

If you are having trouble balancing your workload, talk to your personal tutor, the graduate tutor or whoever else it is who's been assigned to you by the department to manage these cross-module issues.